# How to add and element with a value into an array of objects by using for loop

Tags: typescript, for-loop

I have an array of objects and
I want to add and new id element with increasing value into each object. In the end, I except like this

```
bicycle = [
{
    categorie: 'Road Bike',
    img: '',
    title: '',
    price: '',
    description: '',
    id: 0
},
{
    categorie: 'Road Bike',
    img: '',
    title: '',
    price: '',
    description: '',
    id: 1
}
]
```

For this result, when I try to do it with a for loop. I will get always same id value (not increasing).

```
var bikeObject:any = {
    categorie: 'Road Bike',
    img: '',
    title: '',
    price: '',
    description: ''
}

var bicycle:any = [];

function func(){
  for(let i=0; i < 100; i++){
    bicycle.push(bikeObject);
  }
  for(let i=0; i < 100; i++){
    bicycle[i].id = i;
  }
  console.log(bicycle);
}

func();
```

What should I do to get increasing id values instead of the same. I tried also .map and forEach functions, but all of them gave the same result.

Comment: Your issue is that you're pushing the same object into the array 100 times. If you want 100 different objects, move the `bikeObject` definition inside the first for-loop!

Comment: @DemiPixel thanks, it works. If you add your solution as answer, I can accept this correct solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`bikeObject` is only declared once. This means you're pushing the same object into the array 100 times. You need to move the declaration of `bikeObject` inside the first for-loop. You could also merge the for-loops like so:

```
var bicycle: any[] = [];

function func(){
  for(let i=0; i < 100; i++){
    var bikeObject = {
      id: i,
      categorie: 'Road Bike',
      img: '',
      title: '',
      price: '',
      description: ''
    }
    bicycle.push(bikeObject);
  }
  
  console.log(bicycle);
}

func();
```